# Curl and unit vectors after a change of coordinates

Tags: calculus, geometry, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Let $x,y,z$ be a system of coordinates with unit vectors respectively $\mathbf{u}_x$, $\mathbf{u}_y$, $\mathbf{u}_z$. Moreover, we have

$\nabla = \displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mathbf{u}_x + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \mathbf{u}_y + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \mathbf{u}_z$

Let $x',y',z'$ be a new system of coordinates: $x' = x$, $y' = y$, $z' = -z$.

But what about the unit vector and the Nabla operator?

I suppose the *new* unit vector are $\mathbf{u}_{x'} = \mathbf{u}_x$, $\mathbf{u}_{y'} = \mathbf{u}_x$, $\mathbf{u}_{z'} = -\mathbf{u}_z$.

**Question 1** Is it always so? May we change the coordinates without changing the unit vectors?

We should then have

$\nabla' = \displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} \mathbf{u}_{x'} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y'} \mathbf{u}_{y'} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z'} \mathbf{u}_{z'}$

But if I try to use the old system of coordinates I would obtain

$\nabla' = \displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mathbf{u}_{x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \mathbf{u}_{y} + \frac{\partial}{\partial (-z)} (- \mathbf{u}_{z}) = \nabla$

**Question 2** Is it correct? Or should I have expected another result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should get it out of your head that $\nabla$ is defined in terms of partial derivatives and unit vectors.  This is not generally the case.  Typically, one has

$$\nabla = g^1 \partial_1 + g^2 \partial_2 + g^3 \partial_3$$

where the vectors $g^1, g^2, g^3$ are *not* necessarily unit (or orthogonal, for that matter).

Now then, let

$$f(r) = f(x e_1 + y e_2 + z e_3) =  r' = x' e_1 + y' e_2 + z' e_3$$

You can compute the Jacobian $\underline f$ in the usual manner:

$$\underline f(a) = (a \cdot \nabla) f \implies \underline f(e_1) = e_1, \underline f(e_2) = e_2, \underline f(e_3) = -e_3$$

From here you could compute the transpose $\overline f$, but this transpose is trivially equal to $\underline f$, so I won't bother going through the calculation process.

Now, using the chain rule, you can show that, if you have a scalar field $\phi(r)$ and another corresponding scalar field $\phi'(r') = (\phi' \circ f)(r)$, the chain rule tells us that

$$a \cdot \nabla \phi' = [a \cdot \nabla f] \cdot \nabla' \phi' = \underline f(a) \cdot \nabla' \phi' = a \cdot \overline f(\nabla') \phi'$$

Or, more succinctly,

$$\nabla = \overline f(\nabla')$$

Explicitly, what I've written is the idea that

$$e^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + e^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + e^3 \frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \overline f \left[ e^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + e^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y'} + e^3 \frac{\partial}{\partial z'} \right] = e^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + e^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y'} - e^3 \frac{\partial}{\partial z'}$$

This process is valid for arbitrary coordinate transformations; in particular, if you were to transform to spherical coordinates, it would correctly spit out non-unit vectors for the angular coordinates.

Secondly, I would attribute no geometric significance to the object $\nabla'$.  It is merely a handy construct.  In almost all cases, what you're really interested in is finding an expression for $\nabla$ (which never changes) merely in some different coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry, but I am not very skilled with the Jacobian. But what effectively "doesn't change" between two coordinates systems? The general expression for $\nabla$, written in the beginning of the answer? Maybe, if you could use a geometrical example I can better understand your precise computations.

Comment: So the transformation law $\nabla = \overline f(\nabla')$ tells us that $\nabla$ can be written as $g^1 \partial_1 + g^2 \partial_2 + g^3 \partial_3$ in any coordinate system, for three vectors $g^1, g^2, g^3$.  We need only compute those vectors--which are called (among other terms) the *cotangent basis vectors*.  For instance, the vector $g^1$ is normal to a surface of constant $x^1$. The length of $g^1$ is determiend by how fast $x^1$ changes--conceptually, by a gradient--but since you need $g^1$ to do that, you can also find it by looking at the size and orientation of a surface element.